# In angular bootstrap tabs, how to cancel tab change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, tabs, angular-bootstrap

I want to cancel tab change/panel switch when user clicks another tab and I discover that changes in the current panel are not saved.

I use the `deselect()` attribute of element `<tab>`, [documented here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#tabs), to fire a function in my controller and in which I determine that I shouldn't change tab. Meaning: I don't want to deselect this and select the other that user clicked on.

How can I accomplish this? preferably from inside the controller, or in any other way?

I can't just do `$event.stopPropagation()` since I don't have a `$event` here... what am I missing?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fj5y4WQ4oaEI7FPf2Ilh?p=preview) isolating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you have 3 tabs and want the third tab to be unclickable. Then you should add a `deselect` attribute to clickable tabs, so that when deselect event happens, they checked what tab we're trying to switch to and if it's the third tab, prevented tab switch.

This works only in later versions of ui-bootstrap, around 0.12-0.14, can't say exactly:

`template.html`

```
<uib-tabset class="tab-animation" active="activeTab">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Overview" id="overview" deselect="checkTab($event, $selectedIndex)"></uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="Details" id="details" deselect="checkTab($event, $selectedIndex)"></uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2" heading="Download" id="download"></uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

`controller.js`

```
// Downloads tab shouldn't be clickable
$scope.checkTab = function($event, $selectedIndex) {
    // $selectIndex is index of the tab, you're switching to
    if ($selectedIndex == 2) { // last tab is non-switchable
        $event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Comment: For some reason, $selectedIndex is undefined

Answer (score 0):

My solution to prevent the tab change was using the built in disabled flag. If you add an ng-click handler to the tab, you can still react to events. This works if the disabled styling is no problem for you - in your use case this might be the case.

```
<tab  disabled="true" ng-click="warnUserNotSavedChanges()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this issue comment](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2715#issuecomment-106511455). It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code for this tabs solution, It's worked for me.

```js
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <tabset>
    <tab heading='Tab 1'>Tab 1 content</tab>
    <tab>
      <template tabHeading>
        <div (click)="tryToSwitch($event)">
          Tab 2
        </div>
      </template>
      Tab 2 content
    </tab>
  </tabset>

  `,
})
export class App {
  tryToSwitch(e) {
    let result = confirm('Are you sure?');
    if(!result) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, TabsModule.forRoot() ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thats Angular not AngularJS?

Answer (score -3):

Apply `ng-click` directive to each tab:

```
<tab ng-click="checkChange($event)">
```

and then `preventDefault();`:

```
$scope.checkChange = function($e) {
    // check if tab can be changed
    $e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: I tried that, but $e is undefined, so I get:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined"
There is an "event" defined though, but that's some global and doing preventDefault() on it doesn't help me. I'm not sure what default I'm preventing using that one. Passing $event to both select and deselect gives undefined inside the controller. You refere to "the example" are you refering to what you show here? or is there some working example of this out there?

Comment: BTW thanks for you quick reply. Also note that deselect fires first, then select. I think I should cancel upon deselect.

Comment: Good idea, I tried it before as well. Doing this $event is defined. The problem with this solution, using ng-click, is that at this point we are already on the clicked tab (despite all unwanted stuff that happens when this tab is activated) what are we to cancel? the tab-change has already been made. I guess I could, in some global variable, save what tab was left (in its deselect) and now select it back... but what I really want to do is to cancel the whole thing as soon as possible. 
Sory to say but your update didn't help.

Comment: To clarify: I tried that, the $event is now defined, but $even.preventDefault() is without effect and the newly selected tab remains selected. As the tab tab that shouldn't have been left is left long ago, with the unsaved changes... :-(

Comment: ok, could you provide a fiddle with you problem? we will work that out ;)

Comment: This solution does not work. The function will be called but the tab will still be changed.